# Markov process and unique stationary distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider general homogeneous Markov process $\{X_n\}_{n\in T}$. It means that time can be continuous or discrete and also random variables $X_n$ can be continuous or discrete, for $n\in T$.

I would like to know, that if Markov process $\{X_n\}_{n\in T}$ has unique stationary distribution than it is also limit distribution for this Markov process.

Anny help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Nope; look at a discrete chain with $P=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. It is a really standard counterexample for ergodicity of Markov chains.

Comment: Yes of course. My mistake. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a reminder  .  [Finite state space + equilibrium  (you call it "limit") distribution exists] $\implies$ stationary (another name : invariant) distribution is equilibrium distribution . [irredicible + aperiodic Markov chain + stationary distribution exists] $\implies$   equilibrium distribution is stationary distribution . When Markov chain is irreducible , unique stationary distribution exists $\iff$ Markov chain is positive recurrent .